# Where is mongoimport installed on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I'm trying to setup a cronjob for a regularly scheduled import of json data into a mongo database. To conduct the import, I have the following command in the Python script that the cronjob runs:

```
os.system("mongoimport --jsonArray --db %s --collection %s --file .../data.txt" %(db_name,collection_name))
```

However, the log file of the cronjob keeps displaying the following error:

```
sh: mongoimport: command not found
```

I think I need to call mongoimport with the full file path in the code, but I'm not sure where mongodb/mongod/mongoimport is installed on my system.  whereis mongoimport, whereis mongodb, whereis mongod all return nothing.

I installed mongodb with Homebrew. Packages installed with Homebrew are located in /Library/Caches/Homebrew. However, in my system that folder only has a mongodb-2.6.4_1 tar file. Do I have to unpack this tar file to access mongoimport?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: does `mongo` command works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you installed MongoDB correctly you need to create a `~/.bash_profile` and assign `/usr/local/mongodb/bin` to the `$PATH environment variable`

After that you should be able to access the mongoimport command

Answer (score 68):

As of June 2020,
I installed mongodb latest version using `brew` as per the documentation , and I faced the same issue `command not found: mongoimport` .

I had to to install mongodb-database-tools.

```
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools
```

Then I could use `mongoimport`.

Official [Installing on MacOS docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/) agree.

Comment: This works fine and this is the solution for the issue.

Comment: This answer worked for me. `mongoimport` was not installing with `mongodb-community` or `mongodb-community-shell`. The documentation from MongoDB and the brew tap on GitHub are really misleading about this.

Comment: I guess they are already on your computer but this adds another set of tools to your computer which can be accessed from your path?

Comment: Is there a way to install mongoimport without using brew/port, like just from .tar file?

Comment: @raga
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools
To download manually

Comment: @Sanket9394 Perfect. Thanks I missed it!.

Comment: Worked for me! Maybe you have to link tools after installation: brew link mongodb-database-tools

Answer (score 9):

Got the same issue, but I installed mongodb via Mac Port. Unfortunately, from version 3 of mongodb, these mongodb tools are maintained as a separate project, so I updated Mac port to latest version then installed mongo tools separately.

***sudo port install mongo-tools***

Hope this helps someone that installing mongodb by mac port.

Answer (score 0):

If you used brew for installation, `mongod` is in `/usr/local/bin/` directory. Other utilities (mongoimport, mongoexport etc.) are in the same path. All you need to do is open another terminal.

Comment: As of 2020, this was not the case when I installed from brew. [Sanket9394's answer did fix my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62973387/705296).

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community and you can download a tarball for MacOS, which contains all the tools including `mongoimport`.

Untar, add to you `PATH` and voilà!

Answer (score -3):

Try using `./mongoimport` or `sudo ./mongoimport`

After following all of these examples, I was able to use it that way from `bash`.

Comment: @NicoHaase true, but I don't know if this counts as "randomly".

Comment: This explanation is lacking on so many levels. There's the unix way of how files & folders are structured, and you can't just expect a relative path to work out of the blue. There's the etc folder, the var folder, the home folder, the tmp folder, and many others, each designed for a specific purpose. One of them is used (in 98% of cases) for newly installed softwares, much like the default installation folder in windows is Program Files. And all this without even mentioning the $PATH env variable (which can create all sorts of problems if not sourced properly).