# How to install mongoimport on Mac OS X

Tags: mongodb, macos

I have installed Mongodb following the [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850467/where-is-mongoimport-installed-on-mac-os-x). However, it only has `Mongo` in `usr/local/bin`
When I tried to import a json file into my database, it showed an error message:

> `> mongoimport --jsonArray --db hw4 --collection restaurants --file restaurants.json
>   2019-11-12T15:18:28.737-0600 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
>   @(shell):1:14`

It seems there's no `mongoimport` installed. How could I install it, or is there another way to import data?

Comment: mongoimport is generally available with your MongoDB server installation. Look for the tool in the server installation's `bin` folder. Also,you can find instructions to get it by a separate download; instructions at [mongoimport availability](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html#availability).

Comment: This works, just download the separate function.

Answer (score 0):

The `--jsonArray` option provided with command could be causing the issue, is probably not required. What does restaurants.json look like?

Comment: The restaurants.json can be imported by using Studio 3T. It should be good.

Answer (score -1):

`mongoimport` should be run from the shell command line, not from inside the `mongo` shell.

To ensure the correct installation of MongoDB and its associated tools, please follow the procedure outlined in [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Comment: "zsh: command not found: mongoimport", I think I didn't install it correctly.

Comment: updated the answer with a link to the installation procedure

Comment: Thank you for the link! I have tried and still not working. It shows the same result.